# How can I measure I/O throughput on Heroku Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, resources, measurement

I'm trying to compare the cost of a Heroku Postgres database with other providers (e.g. AWS RDS). While I can easily determine how much memory and storage it uses, how can I determine the amount of I/O the Heroku Postgres database is performing (many services charge for I/O)?